# Chef Difference between package and include_recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

What is the difference between `package` and `include_recipe`?

For example,

`package 'git'`

`include_recipe 'git'`

When would I include a recipe as opposed to declare a package dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`package 'git'` installs a package called `git` using the system packaging system (`apt-get install git`, `yum install git`, etc).

`include_recipe 'git'` executes the default recipe in the `git` cookbook (`git/recipes/default.rb`).

Comment: Oh okay. So the difference here is if it is a system package or a cookbook that you would utilize `package` and `include_recipe`, respectively. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, the community `git` cookbook does a lot more than simply installing the package. It also supports installing on OS X and Windows, configuring git daemons, etc.